# Binding from ViewModel to behaviour

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a property on my ViewModel that I need bound to a BindableProperty in my behaviour but I cant seem to get it to bind.

```
private int _test;
    public int Test {
        get {
            return _test;
        }
        set {
            if (SetProperty (ref _test, value)) {
                _profileIsDirty = true;
                NotifyPropertyChanged ("AllowUpdate");

            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the property in the behaviour

```
        public static readonly BindableProperty MinLengthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MinLength", typeof(int), typeof(MinLengthValidator), 0);

    public int MinLength
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinLengthProperty, value); }
    }
```

This is the property on the ViewModel and this is how I am trying to bind to it in XAML

```
<behave:TelephoneNumberValidatorBehaviour x:Name="phoneValidator" MinLength="{Binding Test, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

But it never binds. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the value of your NotifyPropertyChanged to "Test" instead of "AllowUpdate"? Otherwise the UI is never notified that the value has changed of Test. Instead it raises that the value the AllowUpdate property has changed, which does not exist in your ViewModel.

Comment: Yeah I have, there is a built in notification in the SetProperty method so it isnt that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of BindableProperty.Create should be type of the class where the BindableProperty is defined. Based on your sample, I guess it should be `typeof(TelephoneNumberValidatorBehaviour)` and not <strike>`typeof(MinLengthValidator)`</strike>